# Continuity and differentiability of two variables functions $f(x,y)=\frac{x^a y^b}{x^c+y^d}$.

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

In a previous question I've posed, I've come to know that there is a criterion for check the continuity in the origin of a particular class of functions:

> $${\large
> f(x,y) := \left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
> \frac{x^a y^b}{x^c+y^d}\qquad &\mbox{ if $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$} \\
> 0 \qquad  &\mbox{if  $ (x,y)=(0,0)$}
> \end{array} \right.
> }
> $$

Now, the criterion is this:

$f(x,y)$ is continue in $(0,0)$ iff  $\dfrac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{d}>1$

Anyone can prove this? Also, there is a more general criterion to determine the differentiability of this kind of functions in the origin?

Another question I have, if I have a function like this:

$$
f(x,y) := \left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
\frac{x^a y^b +g(x,y)}{x^c+y^d}\qquad &\mbox{ if $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$} \\
0 \qquad &\mbox{if  $ (x,y)=(0,0)$}
\end{array} \right.
$$

With no parameters on $g(x,y)$ but only the thing that $\frac{g(x,y)}{x^c+y^d} \rightarrow0$ for $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$ implies that sufficient and necessary conditions for the parameters $a,b,c,d$ to make $f(x,y) \rightarrow0$ for $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)$ are the ones that make $ \frac{x^ay^b}{x^c+y^d} \rightarrow0 $ for $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

For one direction (also when $a,b,c,d>0$) you can make the substitution $y=x^{c/d}$.

Then $f$ continuous implies that $x^{a+\frac{bc}{d}-c}\to 0$ so $a+\frac{bc}{d}-c>0$ which implies $a/c+b/d>1$.

I don't think the other direction is true without some more conditions.

Take $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y^2}{x^3+y^3}$ and zero where not defined then:

$f(x,x^2-x)=\frac{(x-1)^2}{1-(x-1)+(x-1)^2}\to \frac13\neq 0$.